# How can I scrape the text from this popup window? [Python and Scrapy]

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, fancybox

Please note - I'm very unexperienced and this is my first 'real' project.

I'm going to try to explain my problem as best as I can, apologies if some of the terms are incorrect.

I'm trying to scrape the following webpage - https://www.eaab.org.za/agent_agency_search?type=Agents&search_agent=+&submit_agent_search=GO

I can scrape the 'Name' and 'Status', but I also need to get some of the information in the 'Full Details' popup window.

I have noticed that when clicking on the 'Full Details' button the URL stays the same.

Below is what my code looks like:

```
import scrapy
from FirstScrape.items import FirstscrapeItem

class FirstSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "spiderman"
    start_urls = [
        
        "https://www.eaab.org.za/agent_agency_search?type=Agents&search_agent=+&submit_agent_search=GO"
        
        ]
    
    def parse(self, response):
        item = FirstscrapeItem()
        item['name'] = response.xpath("//tr[@class='even']/td[1]/text()").get()
        item['status'] = response.xpath("//tr[@class='even']/td[2]/text()").get()
        #first refers to firstname in the popup window
        item['first'] = response.xpath("//div[@class='result-list default']/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/text()").get()
        
        
        return item
```

I launch my code from the terminal and export it to a .csv file.

Not sure if this will help but this is the popup / fancy box window:

[popup window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsJfi.png)

Do I need to use Selenium to click on the button or am I just missing something? Any help will be appreciated.

I'm very eager to learn more about Python and scraping.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Full Detail` you have the `href` attribute you need to get this url and make requests.
Maybe it helps you:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class FirstSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "spiderman"
    start_urls = [
        
        "https://www.eaab.org.za/agent_agency_search?type=Agents&search_agent=+&submit_agent_search=GO"
        
        ]
    
    def parse(self, response):
                
        all_urls = [i.attrib["href"] for i in response.css(".agent-detail")]
        for url in all_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=f"https://www.eaab.org.za{url}", callback=self.parse_data)
        
    def parse_data(self, response):
        print(response.css("td::text").extract())
        print("-----------------------------------")
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the URL you need to extract from your starting page:

```
<a href="/listing_detail.php?agents_id=169039" class="agent-detail">Full Detail</a>
```

To get the content of pop-up-window open this extracted URL as another request.

Comment: Okay, I see. Thank you for your help Lukas.